# Struggle with dataGrid styles WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles

I have problem with dataGrid style, it was working well, but after I change dataGrid style, another style disappear. I put code which is working well, picture of the result, and then what I change and what I get after change. Maybe someone know how it write better?

```
<Style  TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#E6E6E6"/>
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>  
            <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F7F7F7"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                    Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                        Value="2"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="#FFBA59" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
    </Style>
        <!--Style x:Key="HeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#E6E6E6"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
    </Style-->



    <DataGridTextColumn x:Key="product"  Header="  Product"  FontFamily="Arial"  Width="3*" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True"
                        FontSize="18" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="#4D4D4D">
        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="700"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">

                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#E6E6E6"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Key="unit price"  Header="Unit price, € " FontFamily="Arial" Width="0.5*" Binding="{Binding Age}" IsReadOnly="True"
                         FontSize="18" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="#4D4D4D">
        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#E6E6E6"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Key="quantity"  Header="Quantity" FontFamily="Arial" Width="0.7*" Binding="{Binding Country}" IsReadOnly="True"
                         FontSize="18" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="#4D4D4D">
        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#E6E6E6"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Key="price"  Header="Price, €  " FontFamily="Arial" Width="0.3*" Binding="{Binding adress}" IsReadOnly="True"
                         FontSize="18" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="#4D4D4D">
        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="25"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#E6E6E6"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>

    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>  
    </Style> 
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FFD65E" />


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#E6E6E6"/>   
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>


<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="lbPersonList" Margin="30,98,362,30" AlternationCount="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              RowHeight="42" GridLinesVisibility="None" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#E6E6E6" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" 
              HeadersVisibility="Column" >

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="product"/>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="unit price"/>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="quantity"/>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="price"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>


</Grid>
```

I only change dataGrid style:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#E6E6E6"/>   
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black"/>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: The `ControlTemplate` only contains a single border definition. All the other Information is missing of how to format (position, style, ...) the content of the `DataGrid`. What do you want to accomplish? Add a border with rounded cornes to the ´DataGrid`?

Comment: Yes, I want  that DataGrid which is in 1st image  be with rounded cornes

Answer (score 0):

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
```

#FFFFFF denotes white color. You are setting background colour of datagrid as white which is why you are not able to see anything on the screen.

Comment: You about  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">.....? I just delete background property, the result is the same

Comment: You are setting the control template of the datagrid to a border whose radius is 10px and border color is black. Control template defines the visual look and feel of any control. By just providing a border inside the control template, you're basically overwriting the default look and feel of datagrid control.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the template like that, you are wiping out all of the rest of the visual elements that make it a `DataGrid`.
You must pull the default template (either from blend or from msdn) and alter it.

This is what you must modify according to your needs

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="local:DataGrid">
    <Grid>
        <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </vsm:VisualState>
            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="2">
            <Grid Name="Root" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <!--Start: TopLeftHeaderTemplate-->
                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="TopLeftHeaderTemplate" TargetType="localprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Grid Name="Root">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="#FFC9CACA" Background="#FF1F3B53" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                <Rectangle Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1">
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FCFFFFFF" Offset="0.015" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#F7FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.6" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#D1FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
                            </Border>
                            <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" StrokeThickness="1" Height="1" Fill="#FFDBDCDC" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                    <!--End: TopLeftHeaderTemplate-->

                    <!--Start: TopRightHeaderTemplate-->
                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="TopRightHeaderTemplate" TargetType="localprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Grid Name="RootElement">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Border BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFC9CACA" Background="#FF1F3B53" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                <Rectangle Stretch="Fill">
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FCFFFFFF" Offset="0.015" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#F7FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.6" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#D1FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                    <!--End: TopRightHeaderTemplate-->
                </Grid.Resources>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <localprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader Name="TopLeftCornerHeader" Template="{StaticResource TopLeftHeaderTemplate}" Width="22" />
                <localprimitives:DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter Name="ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <localprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader Name="TopRightCornerHeader" Grid.Column="2" Template="{StaticResource TopRightHeaderTemplate}" />
                <Rectangle Name="ColumnHeadersAndRowsSeparator" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" StrokeThickness="1" Height="1" Fill="#FFC9CACA"/>

                <localprimitives:DataGridRowsPresenter Name="RowsPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" />
                <Rectangle Name="BottomRightCorner" Fill="#FFE9EEF4" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" />
                <Rectangle Name="BottomLeftCorner" Fill="#FFE9EEF4" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                <ScrollBar Name="VerticalScrollbar" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Width="18" Margin="0,-1,-1,-1"/>

                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle Name="FrozenColumnScrollBarSpacer" />
                    <ScrollBar Name="HorizontalScrollbar" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="18" Margin="-1,0,-1,-1"/>
                </Grid>

                <dataInput:ValidationSummary Name="ValidationSummary" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" MaxHeight="90"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="False" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" CornerRadius="2" Background="#8CFFFFFF" Opacity="0"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Also note that this is the control template directly from MSDN, you are going to have to import various namespaces and probably a couple of other adjustements.

You may want to read up on [Customizing the Appearance of an Existing Control by Using a ControlTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189093(v=vs.95).aspx)